# Upgraded android studio from 2.3.3 to 3.0.1. Unable to build any project. How to fix

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\e0bf0fd8597eb9c539cbc7097b7e054d\res\values-v14\values-v14.xml
Error:(8, 5) error: resource dimen/abc_text_size_button_material (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:dimen/abc_text_size_button_material) not found.
C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\e0bf0fd8597eb9c539cbc7097b7e054d\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\e0bf0fd8597eb9c539cbc7097b7e054d\res\values-v11\values-v11.xml
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\RecyclerViewWithCardView\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v14\values-v14.xml
Error:resource style/TextAppearance.AppCompat (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/TextAppearance.AppCompat) not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\RecyclerViewWithCardView\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:resource style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize) not found.
Error:resource style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize) not found.
Error:resource style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.
Error:resource style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog) not found.
Error:resource style/Base.V7.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Base.V7.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\RecyclerViewWithCardView\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v11\values-v11.xml
Error:(63) resource style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog) not found.
Error:(64) resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless) not found.
Error:(65) resource bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside) not found.
Error:(68) resource style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog) not found.
Error:(69) resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless) not found.
Error:(70) resource bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside) not found.
Error:(73) resource style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog) not found.
Error:(74) resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless) not found.
Error:(75) resource bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside) not found.
Error:resource style/Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView) not found.
Error:resource style/Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText (aka com.learn2crack.recyclerview.recyclerviewwithcardview:style/Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.EditText) not found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 6s
>   Information:36 errors

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: Also can you post the contents of your build.gradle files?

Comment: Yes i did try to clean the project and then even tried to rebuild the project, but nothing seems to work. I even uninstalled android studio version 2.3 & then installed version 3.0.1. Tried to build a new project, but faced same issue. Is there a fix.

Comment: These are the contents of build. gradle files.

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: @shridhar and your app/build.gradle?